# How is $x\lt 3$ in this following excercise$?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently going through Spivak's calculus, and one of the problems require to find $x$ which satisfies $(x-\pi)(x+5)(x-3) > 0$

My reasoning is that any of the two pairs can be treated as a single pair, and hence we can use our understanding of $(a+b)(c+d)>0$ which was proven earlier in the book.
The problem is that the solution states $x>\pi, -5<x<3$

Shouldn't $x$ be greater than $3?$ There is also the fact that $x > \pi$ but not $x > 3$

Comment: **Hint** A product of some collection of real numbers is positive iff there are an even number of negative factors (and no zero factors).

Comment: There are 3 roots, $-5, 3, \pi$. The function is negative, positive, negative and positive on the interior of the corresponding intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function can change sign, if you check it between the roots($-5,3,\pi)$, so the following intervals should be checked:

Suppose, that $x>\pi$, in that case, your function is **positive.**

Suppose, that $x\in (3, \pi)$, in that case your function is negative.

Suppose, that $x\in (-5,3)$, in that case, your function is **positive.**

Suppose, that $x<-5$, in that case your function is negative.

Solution: $x>\pi \cup x \in (-5,3)$

Comment: Why would it be positive at x belong to (-5,3)? If x is less than 3, (x-3) < 0.

Comment: If $x$ is in $(-5,3), (x-3)<0$ is true, but $(x-\pi)<0$ is true aswell, and $- * + * - = +$(If you multiply two negatives, they become positive). For example, let $x=0$, then you have $(-\pi)*5*(-3)=15* \pi > 0$.

Comment: Yes but if we take the solution, we assume that x > pi and x > -5 but x < 3. This would make the first two brackets positive and the last bracket negative, meaning the outcome would be < 0.

Comment: But we can't assume, that x>pi and x<3 at the same time, that would result in a contradiction. We have x > pi OR x is in (-5,3). Union means OR, not AND. :)

Comment: I just realized how stupid i was. I assumed that pi was a variable instead of the constant. Thank you